# Name of the sauce/salad eaten with roast dinners up north UK

Tags: salad, food-identification, salad-dressing, english-cuisine

Its a sauce that contains lettuce and vinegar to eat with roast dinner and can be eaten with chips and cold meat in Newcastle, UK.

Comment: What is the question?  Are you asking us to identify the name of such a sauce or condiment?

Comment: Maybe it's like like a "Jeopardy" thing

Comment: Are you sure you mean lettuce?

Comment: If you change lettuce to cabbage, it sounds like Cole Slaw.

Comment: It could be pickle, or maybe picallily.

Comment: Could it be mint sauce?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are referring to [coleslaw](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/wordofmouth/2012/oct/04/how-to-make-perfect-coleslaw) - it's actually cabbage rather than lettuce, and is considered a side-dish. It's often served with chips (French Fries here in the US) as an accompaniment to hot and cold roast meats as well as batter-fried dishes such as chicken, clams or fish. Coleslaw dressing can be creamy or vinegary in the US, and it's largely a regional difference - in Southern Cuisine, coleslaw dressing is primarily vinegar, northern recipes call for mayo or sour cream. Reviewing some recipes online, in the UK it appears that coleslaw tends to have both creamy and vinegary components to the dressing.

Comment: Coleslaw isn't eaten with roast dinners anywhere in the UK, unfortunately (or rather, fortunately, because it would be gross).

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean "liquor"? Liquor is  a parsley sauce to which vinegar is often added. It's usually eaten with pie and mash.

Comment: Pie and mash is not a northern UK thing.

Comment: Although more commonly associated with London, it is eaten in the north of England too.

Comment: Pie and mash is eaten everywhere, but "liquor" is definitely a London thing.